# Converting word problems with speed into algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

'A rower travels upstream at $6$ km per hour and back to the starting place at $10$ km per hour. The total journey takes $48$ minutes. How far upstream did the rower go?'

I'm struggling turning the relationships between the data given and forming an algebraic expression. The answer given is $3$ km and I tried
$6x + 10x = 48$ and then solving for $x$ to give $3$ .However I have the feeling that that isn't correct and just a fluke. could anyone explain this problem to me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: $x$ is the distance sought, then $\dfrac{x}{6}+\dfrac{x}{10}=\dfrac{4}{5}$

Comment: Okay I figured it out from your hint :) Hopefully I can get through the rest of the questions now without further hiccups.

Comment: Good. Practice and Practice....